# Pickaday.js not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm having problems with Pickaday.js and I can't see what is the problem.

This is my code:

```
    ...

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pikaday.css">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/pikaday.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/pikaday.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
     var $datepicker = $('#datepicker').pikaday({
           firstDay: 1,
           minDate: new Date('2000-01-01'),
           maxDate: new Date('2020-12-31'),
           yearRange: [2000,2020]
        });    
    </script>

    ....

    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: **So what is your problem**?

Comment: Probably change the order in which you include `pikaday.js` and `pikaday.jquery.js`

Comment: I've tried to change the order. It just doesn't work...

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q95s8/

Comment: It is working everywhere but on my page. I don't understand. It's not working at all. This is so frustrating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to wait for the page to finish loading and add a snippet of code.

Replace this:

```
var $datepicker = $('#datepicker').pikaday({
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: new Date('2000-01-01'),
        maxDate: new Date('2020-12-31'),
        yearRange: [2000,2020]
     });
```

With this:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    var $datepicker = $('.datepicker').pikaday({
       firstDay: 1,
       minDate: new Date('2000-01-01'),
       maxDate: new Date('2020-12-31'),
       yearRange: [2000,2020]
    }); 

    $datepicker.pikaday('show');
});
```

And add this to the inputs `class='datepicker'`

Comment: It works :) But it works only for one input field (first). It doesn't work for the second one.

Comment: I edited my answer, but basically add `class='datepicker'` to the inputs and change `$('#datepicker')` to a `$('.datepicker')` in the javascript.